# How to find the ID of this HTML source

Tags: html, vb.net

I want to find out the [ID of an element](http://i.epvpimg.com/2yZbf.png). I want to find out the ID of the textbox because I need the ID to type into my VB application (from there I will use GetElementbyID to find the element). I tried "futPhishingTextBoxTyped" for the ID but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

The Textbox with the class of "futPhishingTextboxTyped" does not have an assigned ID. You need to refer to it from the FORM parent:

```
document.*formname*.futPhishingTextboxTyped (whatever your form name is)
```

INPUTS are also supposed to be self-closing:

```
<input class="futPhishingTextboxTyped" type="text" maxlength="15" />
```

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for the quick answer but I get an error when I type in "document.*formname*.futPhishingTextboxTyped" (the document part gets this error :  'document' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level)

Comment: By the way this is Visual Basic 2010, sorry for not mentioning.

Comment: *formname* is supposed to be the name of the form you are using.

Comment: Hi, this is what I write: Document.login.futPhishingTextboxTyped my form name is login.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have an id. You could try getting the div and then finding children of it that are inputs with

```
GetElementById("futPhishingAdditional").GetElementsByTagName("input")
```

Going by your comment, the full line might look like this:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("futPhishingAdditional").GetElementsByTagName("input").Item(0).SetAttribute("va‌​lue", TextBox1.Text)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I dont think this will work since I cannot use the .SetAttribute feature. Currently I am using this code to identify elements on a page: "WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("futPhishingTextBoxTyped").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)" but this wont work for the textbox...

Comment: What do you mean when you say you can't use `SetAttribute`? This will return a collection of `HtmlElement`s, you will need to get one of them (probably the first).

Comment: SetAttribute -: Adds a new attribute or changes the value of an existing attribute on the specified element.

Comment: I know what it does. Why do you say you can't use it? `GetElementsByTagName` returns an `HtmlElementCollection`. Get the first item from the collection and it will be an `HtmlElement`. `SetAttribute` is a method of the `HtmlElement` class.

Comment: Sorry was eating im back now.. I'l try it out now + thanks for helping me mate :=)

Comment: What happens (or doesn't happen)? Is there an error? Is `WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("futPhishingAdditional").GetElementsByTagName("input").Item(0)` null?